# Azure App Service | PaaS

Tags: azure

A little help here please.

For a Web Application hosted on Azure App Service, Is it possible to create inbound/outbound rules to restrict the port 80? Or is it completely managed by Azure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are after is not possible within Azure natively.  Your options are HTTP & HTTPS (80 & 443) or HTTPS (443) only.

Your only real option is to use a redirect to push all traffic over to http.  Something like this in a web.config should do:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                 <rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url=".*" />
                     <conditions>
                         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^https://www.my-domain.example$" />
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.my-domain.example/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                 </rule>
             </rules>
         </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

It's dirty and not recommended, and you really should be using an encrypted connection wherever possible, but if you're adamant you want a HTTP only Azure site - this is about your only option.